# TFS migration to new server/new accounts and workspaces problems

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

The company I'm working at is moving TFS to a new server (and new user accounts since now we are using domain accounts). The previous server was on version 2012.4 Express and the new is using TFS 2013 Express.

To do this, I backup the old server databases, migrated them to the new server by using the utilities provided for that matter and ran the upgrade wizard.

The only problem I'm having now is that I can't map the projects to the previous locations on this since it keeps telling me that the project is locked in my previous workspace.

I've used a couple methods that should have worked but keep getting the same error:

- Invoked the webservice ***StapWorkitemCache*** at `http://ServerName:8080/tfs/WorkItemTracking/v3.0/ClientService.asmx` both on the new and the old server
- Ran `witadmin rebuildcache /collection:http://ServerName:Port/VirtualDirectoryName/CollectionName` both on the new and the previous server
- Deleted VersionControl.config from my computer
- Deleted the workspaces by connecting to both the servers on Visual Studio and removing any workspace that I had.

I just keep getting the same error saying that the local folder is locked to the old workspace. How can I solve this once and for all?

#### EDIT:

Is it possible that I should be migrating just the TFS_DefaultCollection database instead of bringing the TFS_Configuration along?

#### EDIT 2

New problem arose:
Nobody can see their projects on the old server. Since I couldn't get the new server to work, I put the old one back online and now nobody can connect and on the web administration page there aren't any projects.

Comment: Did you follow the [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx)? There are many variables in this case.

Comment: Hi. Yes I did follow the guide, and even made one of my own. I think I eventually was able to fix everything, but I'm still in testing. Wasn't easy, that I can tell you for sure.